# Name the film (Movie or TV I don't know which.) End features Man finding his love interest's image in a rock

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for something I watched back in the mid '70s. There was a love story where the man and woman were from two different planets. At the end, she had to go back to her planet and he finds an image of her on a rock while standing at the shore of a body of water (possibly an ocean?)

Any help?

More information. The movie/show was in English and it aired on TV. They couldn't stay together because he couldn't live on her planet? It was on a beach of some sort of ocean, maybe not on Earth. I vaguely remember there being something unusual about the ocean. A space ship was nearby, but I don't remember details about it. This was at the end of the show.

It's been almost 50 years, sorry I don't have more.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I came close. The question is a bit sparse and I'm certain you can come up with more detail. Was it in colour or black&white? What language was it in? What did the woman look like? What did the man look like? Where was it set? How did you know they were from different planets? How did they get to each other? Why did she have to leave? etc